# Why does measure not respect minimal width and height

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does measure not respect `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`.

```
FrameworkElement fe = new FrameworkElement() { MinWidth = 100, MinHeight = 100 };
fe.Measure(new Size(50,50));
// Why: fe.DesireSize == {50; 50} and not {100; 100}?.
```

What is the rationale behind this? Should `MeasureOverride` always return a size at most the available size? Measuring with infinite size does result in `{100; 100}`.

While I'm asking maybe it has to do with `UIElement` that defines the `Measure` method. I guess the `FrameworkElement` cannot weaken the measure post condition with `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`.

Edit: After having another look it appears that the call to Measure should already reflect the constraints from (Minimum/Maximum) Width and Height on the children. The parent is constraining its children to respect the assigned/min/max values.

In my case: `fe.Measure(new Size(fe.MinWidth, fe.MinHeight));` would have been the proper call.

Some background on my use case. I need a panel for an itemscontrol. The items get at maximum a percentage of the "remaining space" but i would like to respect the items minimal width or set width

For example:

Take 2 textboxes first one with a content exceeding 100 length and second one with MinWidth of 100. When MyPanel is smaller than 200 pixels first textbox should leave 100 pixels for second textbox. How to determine the available size of the first textbox? When say the panel has a width of 150. The first textbox shouldn't take 75 but 50. Its almost (in case the second textbox text is empty) like a grid where first columnwidth is * and second columnwidth auto. But now let grid decide the second columnwidth is auto because textbox has a non zero minwidth (or set width). In case the second textbox has lot's of text the grid should behave like second columnwidth is * also.

So far I have:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double desiredWidth = 0;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            desiredWidth += child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        Size result = new Size();
        int i = InternalChildren.Count;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            double availableWidthMinimum = Math.Max(0, (availableSize.Width - result.Width) / i);
            desiredWidth -= child.DesiredSize.Width;
            double availableWidthMaximum = Math.Max(0, (availableSize.Width - result.Width - desiredWidth));
            double availableWidth = Math.Max(availableWidthMinimum, availableWidthMaximum);
            child.Measure(new Size(availableWidth, availableSize.Height));
            result.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            result.Height = Math.Max(result.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
            i--;
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        Point start = new Point(0, 0);
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(start, child.DesiredSize));
            start.X += child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:MyPanel Margin="100,0,0,0">
    <TextBox MinWidth="100" Margin="10">MinWidth=100</TextBox>
    <TextBox MinWidth="0" Margin="10">MinWidth=000</TextBox>
    <TextBox MinWidth="0" Margin="10">Small</TextBox>
    <TextBox MinWidth="0" Margin="10">MinWidth=000</TextBox>
</local:MyPanel>
```

This kind of works but the 1st textbox should stay at least 100 when resizing the window that contains the panel.  And you  will notice that the 4th textBox remains somewhat larger than the 2nd textbox. (Both should first become as small as the 3rd: `[Min200][Large][Small][Large]` -> `[Min200][Small][Small][Small]`)

Answer (score 0):

`DesiredSize` reflects the actual/potential visible size of the element in relation to its container.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=vs.110).aspx:

> **DesiredSize**
>
> Gets the size that this element computed during the measure pass of the layout process.

The way this is calculated by `Measure` is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx):

> public void Measure(Size availableSize)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *availableSize*
>
> Type: System.Windows.Size
>
> The available space that a parent element can allocate a child element. A child element can request a larger space than what is available; **the provided size might be accommodated if scrolling is possible** in the content model for the current element.

(Emphasis mine.)

I've put together a few examples that demonstrate this quite well:

**Element As Button Content**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="DesiredSizeTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <Button.Content>
                <Label x:Name="lbl" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" />
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*In MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(lbl.DesiredSize);
    Debug.WriteLine(lbl.ActualWidth);
    Debug.WriteLine(lbl.ActualHeight);
}
```

*Click Output*

```
50,50
100
100
```

This example is similar to your passing `new Size(50,50)` to `Measure`.

**Switching To A StackPanel**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="50" Height="50" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label x:Name="lbl" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

*Click Output*

```
50,100
100
100
```

**Switching The StackPanel Orientation**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="50" Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="lbl" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

*Click Output*

```
100,50
100
100
```

**Using A ScrollViewer**

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Label x:Name="lbl" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

*Click Output*

```
100,100
100
100
```

**UPDATE**

With regards to the scenario described in the comments below, this is quite dynamic but you could do it with a converter:

```
<Grid x:Name="grd" Width="250">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource glc}" ConverterParameter="1">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="grd" />
                    <Binding Path="MinWidth" ElementName="tb" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.Width>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource glc}" ConverterParameter="0">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="grd" />
                    <Binding Path="MinWidth" ElementName="tb" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.Width>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="............................................................................." />
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="100" Text="............................................................................." />
</Grid>
```

The `StaticResource` "glc" refers to the following converter:

```
public class GridLengthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Count() == 2 && values[0] is double && values[1] is double)
        {
            double gridActualWidth = (double)values[0];
            double tbMinWidth = (double)values[1];

            if (gridActualWidth >= tbMinWidth * 2)
            {
                return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            }
            else
            {
                return parameter.ToString() == "0" ? new GridLength(tbMinWidth) : new GridLength(gridActualWidth - tbMinWidth);
            }
        }

        return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

At runtime, you'd have access to all of the `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` property values if you need to use them.

Comment: The RenderedSize is reflected in ActualWidth and Height. Now your testcase has a larger DesiredSize only because measure uses infinite available space for a stackpanel in one direction and the scrollviewer in both. It does not explain the rationale. As you states that a child could request a larger space than available why doesn’t it do so?

Comment: The way I see it the child *does* request a larger space, but doesn't get it (as there is no scrolling available, and the limit is set at 50 x 50).

Comment: It seems that the available size (constraint) in the call to `Measure` already is constrained to the (Minimum/Maximum) Width and Height. (The parent is constraining its children to respect the assigned/min/max values.) In my case: fe.Measure(new Size(fe.MinWidth,fe.MinHeight));

Comment: Yeah, it has to do with calculating how much of the element will potentially need to be displayed (in terms of size) within the full context of the UI. So, `fe.Measure(new Size(fe.MinWidth,fe.MinHeight));` - that should give you `100,100`?

Comment: Yes, it is a delicate piece of code this measuring and arranging. If you subclass  the elements and you see the flow in measureoverride of all the constraints going up an down the visual tree it all becomes clear. :)

Comment: To bad it doesn't work for a contenpresenter. The contentpresenter doesn't check use the minimal width of it's content.

Comment: Yeah, a `ContentPresenter` of its own has no scrolling capacity. It would need to be wrapped inside of a `ScrollViewer`, `StackPanel`, etc.

Comment: Some background on my use case. I need a panel for an itemscontrol. The items get at maximum a percentage of the "remaining space" but i would like to respect the items minimal width or set width.

Comment: Could you post some code for it, or an image or something? I'm having a hard time envisioning what you mean.

Comment: Maybe this scenario makes it clear: take 2 textboxes first one with a content exceeding 100 length and second one with MinWidth of 100. When MyPanel is smaller than 200 pixels first textbox should leave 100 pixels for second textbox. How to determine the available size of the first textbox? When say the panel has a width of 150. The first textbox shouldn't take 75 but 50. Its almost (second textbox text is empty) like a grid where first columnwidth is * and second columnwidth auto. But now let grid decide the second columnwidth is auto because textbox has a non zero minwidth (or set width).

Comment: in the case the second textbox is has lot's of text the grid should behave like second column is *

Comment: I've added an update to my answer with my thoughts on this.

Comment: I guess it works for the special case with 2 items (I have to test the converters). But I don't think this scales to an arbitrary number of items. Also I should be able to set it as an itemspanel on an itemscontrol.

Comment: Yes, it would need to be programmed specifically per case. And having it as an `ItemsPanel` would add an extra layer of complexity.

Comment: I was thinking about using the visualtree in the measureoverride to determine the absolute minWidth of each item. Still I think DesiredSize should reflect this.

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact requirements, but I imagine there'd be a simpler way using some kind of binding/converter method like the one above.